# BASH Script to move files is not moving files correctly

Tags: bash

I've written a script to move files from the _Incoming directory to ../[A-Z] directories based on the first letter of the file name.

It doesn't appear to be working correctly as all of the remaining files in this directory are being moved into the default '../@' directory.

Here is the script I'm using:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "+-------------------------------------------------------------------+"
echo "|               Removing _ and replacing with space                 |"
echo "+-------------------------------------------------------------------+"
find /run/media/chad/New\ Volume/Chad/_Incoming/ -depth -name '*_*' |
while IFS= read -r f ; do
    mv -iv "$f" "$(dirname "$f")/$(basename "$f"|tr '_' ' ')" ;
done
### Would be nice if this didn't rename the Incoming directory.
### But, since it does...
echo "+-------------------------------------------------------------------+"
echo "| Trying to rename ' Incoming' back to '_Incoming' -- Failure=OKAY  |"
echo "+-------------------------------------------------------------------+"
mv -v /run/media/chad/New\ Volume/Chad/\ Incoming \
      /run/media/chad/New\ Volume/Chad/_Incoming

echo "+-------------------------------------------------------------------+"
echo "|              Sorting and Moving Files based on Alpha              |"
echo "+-------------------------------------------------------------------+"
for i in /run/media/chad/New\ Volume/Chad/_Incoming/\*; do 
    echo "i:$i"
    FILE=$(basename "$i")
    echo "FILE:$FILE"
    LTR=$(echo "${FILE:0:1}" | tr [:lower:] [:upper:] )
    echo "LTR:$LTR"
    NEWFILE="/run/media/chad/New Volume/Chad/$LTR/$FILE"
    echo "NEWFILE:$NEWFILE"
    mv -v "$i" "${NEWFILE//_/ }"
done

echo "+-------------------------------------------------------------------+"
echo "|             Moving the left-overs to the '@' directory            |"
echo "+-------------------------------------------------------------------+"
mv -v /run/media/chad/New\ Volume/Chad/_Incoming/* /run/media/chad/New\ Volume/Chad/@
```

Here is the output when I have a couple of files to move:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
|               Removing _ and replacing with space                 |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
renamed '/run/media/chad/New Volume/Chad/_Incoming/' -> '/run/media/chad/New Volume/Chad/ Incoming'
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Trying to rename ' Incoming' back to '_Incoming' -- Failure=OKAY  |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
renamed '/run/media/chad/New Volume/Chad/ Incoming' -> '/run/media/chad/New Volume/Chad/_Incoming'
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
|              Sorting and Moving Files based on Alpha              |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
i:/run/media/chad/New Volume/Chad/_Incoming/*
FILE:*
LTR:*
NEWFILE:/run/media/chad/New Volume/Chad/*/*
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
|             Moving the left-overs to the '@' directory            |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
renamed '/run/media/chad/New Volume/Chad/_Incoming/Deep-fried Sea Bream - Mukbang eating show.mp4' -> '/run/media/chad/New Volume/Chad/@/Deep-fried Sea Bream - Mukbang eating show.mp4'
renamed '/run/media/chad/New Volume/Chad/_Incoming/HOW TO BUILD A PLANT SUPPORT.mp4' -> '/run/media/chad/New Volume/Chad/@/HOW TO BUILD A PLANT SUPPORT.mp4'
```

Comment: Is the last backslash intended? `for i in /run/media/chad/New\ Volume/Chad/_Incoming/\*`

Comment: Strip down your code until only the problem remains.

Comment: Both of your comments were helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you backslash-escape a `*`, it is no longer a wildcard. So

```
for i in /run/media/chad/New\ Volume/Chad/_Incoming/\*; do
```

does not do what you expect, and what it does is evident from the debugging output (i.e. it sets `$i` to the non-existing directory `/run/media/chad/New\ Volume/Chad/_Incoming/*`.

When you fix that, you'll find that

```
mv -v /run/media/chad/New\ Volume/Chad/_Incoming/* /run/media/chad/New\ Volume/Chad/@
```

doesn't really do what you want, because all of the newly created directories in `/run/media/chad/New\ Volume/Chad/_Incoming/` will match the glob and get moved into `@`.

Comment: That was it. Thanks! -- I'm pretty new to bash scripting and all of the quotes, backslashes, etc, need to be carefully attended to!